# What's the default timeout on the SmtpClient object?

Tags: .net, smtpclient

What does the timeout default to in the .NET SmtpClient object?  What unit of time is it (seconds, milliseconds, etc)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default value is 100,000 (100 seconds).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx

Comment: @Jim Mischel: No, I want you to transfer all your money to my bank account ;)

Comment: The documentation around SMTPClient is really weak. It would have been good for them to tell us that it was in milliseconds!

Comment: @Carl It does state that it's in milliseconds. Take a closer look.

Comment: I've always had a pet hate for properties like this. In my opinion the units for the value should be included in the name: `TimeoutMs` rather than `Timeout`.

Answer (score 2):

The unit is milliseconds, and the default value is 100,000 which is equivalent to 100 seconds.